# How do I have multiple GET buttons with multiple handlers on a ASP.NET Core razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a Razor file with search and download functionality.

1. The user can enter text, click search and the list of files is filtered.
2. The user can also click a download button next to each file.

The search functionality works.

When the user clicks download, the OnGet handler is called instead of OnGetDownload.

Here is the cshtml.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form>
    Search
    <input type="text" asp-for="FilenameFilter" class="form-control" placeholder="Filename ..." autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<form>
    Download
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>File Name</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var file in Model.Files)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@file</td>
                    <td><button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Download" asp-route-name=@file>Download</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here the C# code.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string FilenameFilter { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Files { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        Files = new List<string> { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //This gets called for all button events (search  and download)
        _logger.LogInformation($"OnGet {FilenameFilter}");

    }

    public void OnGetDownload(string name)
    {
        //This is not being called <---------------------------------
        _logger.LogInformation($"OnGetDownload {name}");
    }
}
```

In the browser developer tools I can see that the route seems to be correct i.e.

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/?name=file3.txt&amp;handler=Download">
```

---

**Update**

If I change the second form to `<form method="post">` and the handler to Post then the download handler is called. But semantically this is not a post method. How do I have 2 get handlers?

---

**Update**

Here is the update to the cshtml file (for the comment from Chetan Ranpariya). The problem persists.

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<form>
    Search
    <input type="text" asp-for="FilenameFilter" class="form-control" placeholder="Filename ..." autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

Download
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>File Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var file in Model.Files)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@file</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="get" action="OnGetDownload">
                        <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Download" asp-route-name=@file>Download
                        </button>
                    </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should have form created inside for each loop and set it action attribute to `OnGetDownload`

Comment: `<form action="OnGetDownload">` this should be inside `td` inside for each loop

Comment: @ChetanRabpariya Thanks  for the reply. Does not work (when I move the form inside the loop).

Comment: Can you update the code in question with latest code and explain `does not work`?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya Okay I've updated.

Comment: @direvag, Please check my reply, whether it achieves your requirement? If it solved the problem, I suggest you to try to mark it as an accepted answer for this question when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **Post** method to submit the form and call the handler. Please modify your code as below:

```
                <form method="post">
                    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Download" asp-route-name=@file>Download
                    </button>
                </form>
```

Code in the page index.cshtml.cs (Using Post method):

```
public void OnPostDownload(string name)
{
    //This is not being called <---------------------------------
    _logger.LogInformation($"OnGetDownload {name}");
}
```

Then, the screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information about using Handler, check [Handler Methods in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods).